# Animation Starts After The Page Load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

There is a master page and a few content pages. When navigating, I would like the pages to have a fade-in effect, when they load. When clicked on a link, the page appears first and then the fade-out effect starts after that, but it should be the other way.

**JS:**

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $(".divLoading").fadeOut(2000);
});
```

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Content ID="content" ContentPlaceHolderID="" runat="server">
<div class="divLoading"></div>
   //all the page content comes here
```

**CSS:**

```
.divLoading
{
 width:100%;
height:100%;
background:white;
z-index:1000;
position:fixed;
}
```

I also tried placing the JS and the div in the master page instead of each content page, but its the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your content with a div (e.g. `<div id="divLoading">`) and in your css put this:

CSS:

```
 div#divLoading { display: none; }
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#divLoading').fadeIn(2000);
    });
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DuZ6J/)

Comment: Does it apply for all pages, if put in master.`div id="divLoading"><asp:contentplaceholder..../></div>`....Now the pages wont display.

Answer (score 1):

You are using height in percentage which seems to be not working. Add the following css:

```
html,body{
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No change. The page appears first and then the effect starts